# How to get rid of blinking artifact/bug inside text input and React select input in Electron?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, input, electron

I am currently experiencing a very weird visual artifact in all my text inputs that looks like this:

[It can be seen in this GIF while I type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zv04.gif)

I have tried different solutions such as:

- Applying `spellCheck={false}` to my input components
- Applying `spellcheck: false` to my `webPreferences` inside my Electron preferences

I'm not sure what else it could be or how to fix it. Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Can you test that on a different machine?

Comment: Yep have tested on different machines and my friend also gets the same issue with Electron + text inputs in his application (different code base) @BadalSaibo